# User rep discrepancy

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, users-page

I have noticed for several users that there is a difference in rep between the personal [profile](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/83/jippie) page and the [Users](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users) overview page? I have noticed it for different users, one of which is myself. The difference is alway 101 ('Association Bonus'+1).

What is the cause and will it be solved?

Comment: +1 noticed that as well with my account.

Answer (score 3):

The Users page shows reputation gained from participating on the site in a given period of time (by default, a rolling month).

The 100-point association bonus and the initial 1 point everyone starts with aren't included in the "reputation gained in the past [week|month|quarter|year]" views, but is included in the final "all" view:

[image]

Comment: Still the Arduino stack is less than a month/quarter/year and these numbers are incorrect. Only 'all' shows correct numbers. My association bonus is dated Feb 12, I'd expect to see it in the month view. Good news is that the rep is not entirely lost.

Comment: @jippie As I said, the association bonus isn't included (on purpose) in the views that aren't "all".

Comment: Ah I missed that sentence. Thnx for explaining.